# Rolling rounded image using css3 /jquery on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

My div box contain rounded image which I want to roll (like rolling ball on floor) after page load.After rolling I want to place image at perfectly center of box.

css:

```
#box{width:900px;height:150px;position:relative;background:red;overflow:hidden;}

    .ball{width:150px;height:150px;position;absolute;bottom:0;right:-150px;background:green;}

    .ball img{display:block;width:100%;height:100%;border-radius:50%;}
```

html:

```
<div id="box">
       <div class="ball><img src="http://blog.wiziq.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/5-150x150.png"</div>
 </div>
```

help me for rolling ball effect using css3/jquery

My edit:

css:

```
.ball{
    position:absolute;width:150px;height:150px;right:-150px;
        -moz-transition:all 5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 5s ease;
    -o-transition:all 5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 5s ease;
    transition:all 5s ease;
}

.rotate{-moz-transform:rotate(-940deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-940deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-940deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-940deg);
    transform:rotate(-940deg);}
```

js:

```
$('.ball').animate({'right':375}, {duration:500});
$('.ball').addClass('rotate');
```

Now I need to calculate the accurate angle and right position of the ball outside div box , so rolling of ball stop perfectly at middle of the box.help me please

Comment: You want the image to be horizontally center of div right?

Comment: yes! actually my box and ball are of same height.

Comment: Ok i will create a fiddle and post it.Check for an answer later

Answer (score 1):

place your ball div in a container.

```
<div class="ball-container">
    <div class="ball">...</div>
</div>
```

Use a rotational transition on .ball and a horizontal transition on .ball-container. The number of rotations should be the:

(distance travelled)/Math.PI

When I used css3 transitions I used keyframes for positioning.

```
@-webkit-keyframes{       /*safari and chrome */
    from { left: 270px;} 
    to { left: 1920px; } 
}

@ keyframes{             /* firefox*/
    from { left: 270px;} 
    to { left: 1920px; } 
}
```

The start and end position are set the same as you would position any element using css.

For tips on how to use transitions check out [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) there are some great references at the end of the article.

Answer (score 1):

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/996PJ/5/)

**CSS:**

```
#box{
    width:900px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ball{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    transition:all 3s ease ;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.ball img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
 }
```

**JQuery:**

```
var s=$('.ball').position(); 
$('.ball').css({'position':'absolute'});
$('.ball').animate({'left':''+s.left+'px'});
$('.ball').css({'-moz-transform': 'rotate(360deg)'});
```

Comment: thanks zword! ball is perfectly at middle but i want css3 animation like this: http://tangledindesign.com/demos/css3-transitions/active/

Comment: @galexy i updated my fiddle.It took time because i had to make it work in mozilla and webkit browsers.

Comment: Also run the script again in jsfiddle after its loaded because sometimes jsfiddle doesnt show output on first load.So run it

Comment: I have seen yours fiddle , but this ball is rotating on axis itself instead of rolling on rim, check my edit, hopes you can help me.